# AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process' - ChromeDriver Use

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, attributeerror

receiving the following error when attempting to run Chrome Driver via my Selenium Test in CodeSpace/Workspace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/117965322/SeleniumTest", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 106, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 117, in assert_process_still_running
    return_code = self.process.poll()
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

The code I'm running currently is the below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

ser = Service("/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

I've added the `selenium.webdriver.chrome.service` line as it removed an issue with the executable path, but not the final Attribute Error?

Any help would be fantastic as have exhausted my Googling capabilities!

Just trying to initially get ChromeDriver working for another project but can't get it to launch due to the above error.